# How can I show that this function is a 1-Lipschitz function?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Given $f: \mathbb{Z}_5 \to \mathbb{Z}_5$ such that for some fixed $N \in \mathbb{N}$

$$f(x)= x + 5^N (-x_N +x_N^2 +3)$$
I want to show that $f$ is 1-Lipschitz such that $f$ is induced with the p-adic metric.

I started with letting $x \equiv y $ (mod $p^k$). Hence, I need to show that $f(x) \equiv f(y)$ (mod $p^k$), for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I get

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) -f(y) &=& x-y + 5^N (-x_N + x_N^2 + y_N - y_N^2) \\
&\equiv& 5^N (-x_N + x_N^2 + y_N - y_N^2) \text{ (mod } 5^k)\\
&\equiv& 0 \text{ (mod } 5^k)
\end{eqnarray*}

But this is only true for $k \leq N$. How do I show that $f(x) \equiv f(y)$ (mod $p^k$) is also true for $k>N$?

Comment: What does the notation $x_N$ mean for $x\in\mathbb Z_5$ and $N\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: @ChrisCulter $x_N \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. It's the coefficient of $5^N$ in the p-adic expansion of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $k \gt N$ then $x_N = y_N$ when $x \equiv y \pmod {p^k}$.